# Positively defined symmetric matrix. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is positively defined symmetric matrix. Then:
**a.** $\det_n(A) > 0$
**b.** matrix $A$ is diagonalizable
**c.** it is possible that matrix $A$ has $0$ on diagonal.
**My approach:**
**a.** Yes, positively defined symmetric matrix has Cholesky decomposition, hence $\det(A)=\det(LL^T)=\det(L)\det(L^T)=\det(L)\det(L)=\det^2(L)>0$.  We know that $L$ is non-singular and triangular - hence $\det(L) \neq 0$.
**b.** yeah, it is true. Symmetric matrix is normal matrix, so using spectral theorem we conclude diagonalization.
**c.** Yes, it is true.  It is easy to see this using Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ and fact about non-zero diagonal elements in $L$.
Can you check my answers and explanations, please  ?

Comment: The correct terminology is that $A$ is "symmetric and positive definite."  Note that simply having the determinant of $A$ greater than 0 is not sufficient to ensure that $A$ is positive definite.  Your answers to parts (b) and (c) are simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (c), if $A$ is positive-definite then for every non-zero vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $v^T(Av)>0$, i.e.
$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}v_iv_j>0 $$
where $A=[a_{ij}]$. In particular, taking $v=e_k$ (the $k$th standard basis vector), we see that
$$ a_{kk}=\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}v_iv_j>0 $$
because the only non-zero term in the sum is when $i=j=k$. So the diagonal entries of $A$ must be positive.

The answers to (a) and (b) look fine, though in (b) I don't think you need to use the fact that $A$ is normal, since the spectral theorem states that (real) symmetric matrices can be diagonalized.

Comment: So, for (b) what should I use ?

Comment: The spectral theorem for real symmetric matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices

Comment: Analogously negatively defined matrix has only negative elements on diagonal, yeah?

Comment: Yes, the same argument should work for negative definite matrices.